# iPhone : Is it possible to get each different text in alert for local notification?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios4, uilocalnotification

My app use to select different text data from the database. And we have functionality which display local notification every day.

I am using following code :

```
UILocalNotification *localNotif = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
if (localNotif == nil)
    return;
localNotif.fireDate = [itemDate addTimeInterval:-(minutesBefore*60)];
localNotif.timeZone = [NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone];

localNotif.alertBody = @"Hey";   // Can I select random message for this notification?
localNotif.alertAction = NSLocalizedString(@"View Details", nil);

localNotif.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName;
localNotif.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 1;

NSDictionary *infoDict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:item.eventName forKey:ToDoItemKey];
localNotif.userInfo = infoDict;

[[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:localNotif];
[localNotif release];
```

Now Is it possible to display different text data for local notification? How ?

Comment: can you give an example of your different text that you want to display.

Comment: @Leena : Any random say : localNotif.alertBody = @"Hey"; else localNotif.alertBody = @"Hello"; else localNotif.alertBody = @"OH great";

Comment: create an array of strings then randomly choose the string and assign it to your localnotification.alertbody

Comment: but I am repeating it every day. So it will display same message every day. I want to display different message.

Comment: i don't think so it is possible.

Comment: What is the problem for creating array and randomly choose string ? Though you are displaying it everyday it would be random only...

Comment: @Jennis : Local notification will be set on any button click. So at that time it will generate any random message and its repeating everyday. So lets say you are not opening app again and you are not clicking on set button so it will display only last message. Thats problem. I want to generate randomly. Is that possible ?

Answer (score 0):

you can create an array of string and every time choose a random object and assign it to localnotif body .

Comment: @ : Above code will run only once when your setting the localnotification. So it will choose one message and next day it will display same... where I want random.